# Is ServerSocket.close() supposed to close all open sockets?

Tags: android, serversocket

In my app, I open a `ServerSocket` and listen for and handle connections like so:

```
while(isRunning) {
     try {
         socket = serverSocket.accept();
         new ThreadToHandleIt().start(socket);
     } catch (IOException e) {

     }
}
```

And then at the end (after I would set `isRunning = false`), I close the serverSocket, like so:

```
try {
    serverSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

My question is: when I call [serverSocket.close()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29) at the end, will that automatically also close all the sockets I spawned off for handling? Or do I have to manually close all of them myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev guide at

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29

says

> Closes this server socket and its implementation. Any attempt to connect to this socket ?thereafter will fail.

so going by the wording, you'll have to close each socket individually